# how to convert promise.all to observables

Tags: angular

I have this particular code which sends a file to an api using promises.. the api accepts one file at a time and i have multiple files..so i used a promise array and promise.all
sample code as below

```
            const docPromises = new Array<Promise<ResponseType>>();
            for (const doc of docs) {
                docPromises.push(this.sendDoc(doc));            
            return Promise.all(docPromises).then(
                (responses: ResponseType[]) => {                  
                    return resolve();
                },
                (error: Response | any) => {                  
                    return reject(error);
                }
            )
                .catch((error: Response | any) => {                
                    return reject(error);
                });
```

in the this.sendDoc, i am doing this.http.post

How can i change this to rxjs? i looked up a bit..but nothing i can find for promises.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rxjs [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) is the alternative for Promise.all

```
someFunction() {
    const docPromises = new Array<Promise<ResponseType>>();
    for (const doc of docs) {
        docPromises.push(this.sendDoc(doc));
    }
    return forkJoin(...docPromises).map(
        (responseAsArr) => {
            // do something here if you want to, manipulate the response,
            // (if not then no need of map)
            return responseAsArr
        }
    ).catch((exception) => {                
        return throwError(exception);
    });
}

// call It like:

context.somefunction().sunscribe((data) => {
    // success
},(err) => {
    // err
}, () => {
    // complete
})
```

Comment: @Jocket: yes, so the solution in this answer doesn't use promises, I didn't get your question.

Comment: I mean const docPromises = new Array<Promise<ResponseType>>(); how to rewrite this as well

Comment: @Jocket Yeah, sorry, that should be `docPromises = new Array<Observable<ResponseType>>();`. Please update your your question and include the implementation of  `sendDoc()` method, it should be returning Observables now.